# Custom AuthorizeAttribute not working properly

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

I'm using MVC5 and wanted to have a nice little class like suggested in questions here - an attribute that allows to pass multiple roles for role authorization. Definition looks like this:

```
 public class AuthorizeRolesAttribute : AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        public AuthorizeRolesAttribute(params string[] roles)
        {
            Roles = string.Join(",", roles);
        }
    }
```

The usage is (for example) like this:

```
    [AuthorizeRoles("Admin", "SuperAdmin")]
    public ActionResult CompanyContacts()
    {
        return View();
    }
```

Also, in web.config I added next line:

```
<system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
</system.webServer>
```

And it still allow users to have access to the method. It even ignores the constructor at all. The default attribute works just fine. It seems like I'm missing something. Any advice?

Thank's!

Comment: have you registered your attribute in attributes ? and have you provided implementation of onActionExecuting method in attribute?

Comment: No. The reason is - I just want the default attribute to have an ability to accept multiple roles not as a single string, but like parameters. All other behavior of Authorize is good for me.

Answer (score 0):

your code is working fine, if you changed the user role you have to logout and login again because the old credentials will remain valid till the login session ends.

Comment: Well, no. I dont change the role on the fly. A just login as a simple user and trying to access "admin" method via address. The thing is, that constructor is not called at all. Mb this is a part of the reason.

Comment: Can you send a sample project? cuz it is not possible to regenerate the same situation here!